# Knife cookbook delete without prompt or confirmation window

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-plugins, chef-recipe, knife

Usually when we  run `knife cookbook delete cookbook1` command, we get prompt for confirmation(Yes or No). Is there anyway I can avoid this confirmation and delete the cookbook right away?

I am trying this because I want to execute the same in Jenkins. As of now, I am obviously getting and end of file error with prompt screen as output .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
knife cookbook delete cookbook1 -y
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo Y | knife cookbook delete cookbook1`

Figured it out.